# javascript for is not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

First time trying javascript and i cant find a solution about this.
I need a open/close div button.

if div1 is not visible and i press button 1

set it visible

set all other not visible

elseif div1 is visible and i press button 1

set it not visible

this is my code so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display=='block')
        {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';

            for (i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                document.getElementById(i).style.display='none';
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<button onclick="toggle_visibility(1);">
    1
</button>

...

<button onclick="toggle_visibility(5);">
    5
</button>
```

i forgot this ->

```
<div id="1" style="display:none">
1
</div>

...

<div id="5" style="display:none">
5
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="yourId"> and ideally the ID shouldn't start with a number

Comment: Under html5 an `id` can start with a number.

Comment: my problem is that i cant hide the visibled div, maybe something wrong with for

Comment: why don't you loop thrue all and just make the right one visible in a second step?

Comment: how? plz help, i am new in javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no element with a id. And a id must not begin with an number (in (X)HTML, but not HTML5)! If you just want to show one element try my `showOnly` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var i; // omiting this causes a global variable
        if (document.getElementById("a"+id).style.display=='block')
        {
            document.getElementById("a"+id).style.display='none';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("a"+id).style.display='block';

            for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
            {
                document.getElementById("a"+i).style.display='none';
            }
        }
    }

    function showOnly(id) {
        for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            document.getElementById("a"+i).style.display='none';
        }
        document.getElementById("a"+id).style.display='block';
    }
</script>

<div id="a1" onclick="toggle_visibility(1);">1</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="a5" onclick="toggle_visibility(5);">5</div>
```

See also this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFmFk/1/).

Comment: +1. With regard to complete compatibility: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Could you provide some useful informations? How should I help you with this information that it simple does not work? Copy an error message from a error console or better try e.g. Firebug for Firefox and check where your code breaks.

Comment: there is no error message, it is not working.
if i run onclick event, it opens the div, but it is not closing the other one. i also use some button for onclick event, check my question.

Comment: @zPuls3 I had an error with the index. The loop has to start with index 1. See also my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFmFk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ID attribute from your div's.

```
<div id="yourId">
```

Ideally the ID shouldn't start with a number.

In addition you can use the browser console window to help identify such problems.

Comment: Except in html5, where an `id` *can* start with a number.

Comment: Yes but I still stand by ideally it shouldn't

Comment: `document.getElementById(i).style.display='none';` is correct `i` it the loop variable.

Comment: @Dave: why? It's perfectly valid, and so long as the doctype is specified, shouldn't be a problem (except, perhaps, for older browsers).